# why does mkfs.vfat on a file followed by dd into a disk image not work?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, fat32

I create a 100M disk img and partition it with `sgdisk` to create a BIOS boot and a ESP partition.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.img bs=1M count=100
sgdisk --clear -n 1:2048:4095 -t 1:ef02 -c 1:'BIOS Boot' -n 2:4096:17983 -t 2:ef00 -c 2:'EFI System Partition'
```

I then create a partition and format it for FAT:

```
losetup -f file.img -P
mkfs.vfat /dev/loop0p2
```

1. If I mount the `/dev/loop0p2`, no problem.
2. If I copy the *partition* out of the disk img and mount it, no problem:

   dd if=file.img of=part2.img bs=512 count=13888 skip=4095

Now, `part2.img` is mountable directly. Of course, if I `dd` it *back* into the image, it remains mountable

```
dd if=part2.img of=file.img bs=512 count=13888 seek=4095 conv=notrunc
```

Mount of `/dev/loop0p2` works fine.

However, if I create an identically sized partition img:

```
mkfs.vfat -C directpart.img 13888
dd if=directpart.img of=file.img bs=512 count=13888 seek=4095 conv=notrunc
```

The file `directpart.img` can be mounted, just like `part2.img` (which was extracted from the disk image) can. However, mounting `/dev/loop0p2` no longer works.

What does `mkfs.vfat` do differently when applied to a *partition* in a disk img file (or real block device) from a *standalone* file?

Interestingly, if I use `losetup` to get the full-disk image, the `dd if=<new_file> of=/dev/loop0p2` works with *both* the direct `mkfs.vfat -C <new_file>`  created file *and* the file created by `dd` off the disk.

Comment: What exactly do you mean / did you do by "dd it into the exact partition in the original disk image"?

Comment: And how is that file.img mentioned in the first paragraph involved? Your post is quite confusing to be honest...

Comment: OK, I can update it.

Comment: Is that clearer?

Comment: You should seek=4096, coz the partition start from LBA 4096, which means there are 4096 blocks before it (LBA 0 - LBA 4095).

Comment: That simple? A typo because I was looking at sector end vs start? I will look...

Comment: I don't believe it! It really is that simple. @TomYan post it as an answer. I put the output here from a script run, and had a typo in the script. Sigh.... Thanks!

Comment: Also, one thing off-topic, type `ef02` in reality should not be used for an ESP. ef00 is the type to use. BIOS boot partition is used by grub only for embedding its core.img and hence should not be formatted. Suggested size is 1~2MiB.

Comment: Tom yeah that was just copying typo. `ef00` is the partition type I am using for ESP. `ef02` is for the BIOS boot sector (actually, I am not using bios here at all, just modified from an earlier multi-bios boot disk).

Comment: Ah I misread your sgdisk command. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 4096 for seek= and skip=, because the second partition starts from LBA 4096, which means there are 4096 blocks before it, namely LBA 0 - 4095.

Comment: Also known as, PEBKAC a.k.a. "user made a dumb mistake in copying and didn't realize what he did." Thanks to TomYan for finding it.